# Access data from one collection to another MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this user model made on the nodejs server:

```
const mongoose = require ('mongoose')
const user = new mongoose.Schema({
id:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
},
name:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
email:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
},
pass:{
    type: String,
    required: true
},
company:{
    type: String,
},
});
const User = mongoose.model("user", user)
module.exports = User
```

And I have this jobs model that has a user field like a "Foreign key" and contains the user _id:

```
const job = new mongoose.Schema({
jobtitle :{
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
salary:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
jobemail:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
schedule:{
    type: String,
    required: true
},
user:{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    unique: true,
    required: true
    },
    });
const Job = mongoose.model("job", job)
module.exports = Job
```

So how can I access the name of the user through the field user in the job's collection?

Comment: You can populate `user` field of `Job` collection to populate `user` key with the referenced document. [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#population)

Comment: i don't understand you, how do i populate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can populate the `Job` model and then retrieve `user` properties with:

```
const job = await Job.findOne({}).populate('user').exec();
console.log(job.user.name);
```